# .net Core API and Angular SPA

Tags: angular, api, security, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api written in .net core and an angular application that accesses methods on the API. I've secured the api with JWT authentication so when the application first boots up it logs into the application to get the JWT token to access the API. The problem is I want to lock down certain methods on my API so they can only be accessed by the SPA and not by a third party. If i switch the develper tools on I can see my app call my api to get the JWT token but whats to stop any one else doing this and having full access to my API?

Comment: that's how jwt token works , please read to know more : https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: I know, but how do I stop someone using an application like postmaster to post messages to my API such as AddToBasket, I want only my website to be able to call the method

Answer (score 0):

Using JWT Tokens allows you can restrict access to your application to specific audience e.g your Angular SPA. To do so, when you add authentication to your .net core app define target audience in authentication configuration like so:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", jwtBearerOptions =>
            {
                jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, // verify signature to avoid tampering
                    IssuerSigningKey =
                        new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret)),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = appSettings.AppIssuer, // site that makes the token
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = appSettings.AppAudience, // site that consumes the token
                    ValidateLifetime = true, //validate the expiration 
                    ClockSkew = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0), // tolerance for the expiration date
                };
            });
```

As you can see I store the information about the audience in my `app.settings.json` file. Assuming you are running your angular SPA on `http://localhost:4200`
You can now configure you app.settings like this:

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Secret": "secretKey",
        "AppIssuer": "http://localhost:5000", //this is address of you web api
        "AppAudience": "http://localhost:4200"
    }
}
```

From now on every request that doesn't come from `http://localhost:4200` will be unauthorized.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand how this is secure, if you can monitor the call from the client application to the api then what stops anyone calling the api? Does the spa need some kind of server generated key to ensure the api is only receiving requests from the Web application?

Comment: Using JWT Tokens allows you to restrict access to your application by using a secret key that is known only by your web API. It is hashed in JWT token that you generated for API consumer. Every request with JWT token will be validated if the secret key from client matches secret stored in your API.